# Equation to find unknown point on arc from radius, starting x/y, and ending y

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Basically I want to extend an arc along an axis by a given amount. I can do it easily in CAD, but I'd really like to know if there's an equation I can use to figure it out. It's been about 20 years since I've done this kind of math and it seems like there should be a way, but I haven't found it. I've found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14384217/1695687) that were trying to do something similar, only with the arc angle, which I do not know. It won't let me embed the image so I had to link it.

In my example, I want to extend the arc along the X axis by 0.100

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Auy9Q.png)

Comment: What do you mean "extend the arc along the $x$-axis by $0.1$"? Do you mean to make it a $10$ percent "wider"?

Comment: Extend it by 0.100 units. Inches, millimeters, whatever. I don't think the type of unit would matter.

Answer (score 0):

The equation for the whole line presumably takes the form $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = R^2$, so if you just type that into wolfram twice, replacing $x$, $y$ and $R$ with the values you already know, it should give you two solutions for $(a,b)$. Only one of these is the centre of the circle that produced the arc, but it should be clear. Once you have that you have the equation of the line so you can extend the arc by however much you like, Hope this helped!